# Bosch 800 Series Dishwasher Installation

Tags: dishwasher, installation

I am planning an install of a Bosch 800 series dishwasher and would like some ideas on alternative routing of drain hose, power, and water supply.  This is a replacement not new construction. The area for the dishwasher is right of the sink cabinet, the back wall is concrete block that is furred and dry walled, the counter is 3CM granite, the floor is concrete slab (no basement), with ceramic tile that runs under all cabinets to the walls. Both cabinet sides and backs are 3/4", 5 ply prefinished plywood.  Existing power is a Romex 12/2 w ground cable exiting from the drywall near the right rear of the area. The previous dishwasher was a KitchenAid, hard wired, with drain hose entering sink cabinet near countertop, high loop down to garbage disposal inlet. The water supply line entered the sink cabinet just above the floor of the cabinet near its rear wall.

The Bosch Series 800 dishwasher has connections at the rear, and is fully cased, which is to say there is little clearance on any of the six sides, just an area running across the rear at floor level up a few inches for the connections.  The power connection is a Bosch proprietary connector.

I am looking for ideas for routing the drain hose as the sink cabinet has 2 sliding Rev-a-Shelf
units installed side by side.  Bosch installation directions call for entry of the power, drain and water supply to be in an area up to 2 1/2 inches from the back wall, and no higher than 7 inches from the floor.  In my sink cabinet the top of the cabinet floor is 3 inches above the kitchen floor and the sliding shelf takes up another 6 inches of height (chromed wire sides and bottom).  I really would like to keep the sliding shelves.  This would mean making a higher penetration than the Bosch specified 7 inches from floor (then there's the diameter of the hole as well), but where can I find the room for the drain hose (about a 1 inch OD) to fit between the dishwasher itself and the sink cabinet?  The sink toe kick is a cut down 2x finished with a 1/4" plywood to match the cabinet faces.  Not impossible to cut away, then try to fish the drain line up through the bottom of the cabinet between the rear of the 2 sliding shelves.  Doesn't seem like the smartest way.  I could also remove the drywall from the rear wall near the and behind the sink cabinet and see if the hose could be slipped up behind, then into the sink cabinet.  I am sure I am missing some simple way to do this which why I am reaching out to our group.
[[image: Sink cabinet with slide out shelf, right side shows exiting holes for previous dishwasher]]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTjS7.jpg)
[image: Space for dishwasher install, tile floor, granite top, playwood sides, dry wall on furred block]

Comment: You should fix the power to the disposal so it's not dangling be the loose wires.  If there isn't enough slack in the armored cable to do this properly, you can install a junction box on the wall of the cabinet and add a new equipment tail from there.

Comment: Agreed Jay. The plan once routing hoses and cables is resolved is to put a 2 gang box at the back wall, with a GFCI for the garbage disposal and another GFCI for the dishwasher.  Each is on a different breaker.  The Bosch comes with its own plug, and I have a good pigtail with plug to connect the garbage disposal.  I think if questions arise with that work, I should probably ask a separate question.  Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the best option is to cut a hole in the side of the cabinet, below the bottom and another in the bottom of the cabinet. The location would be the best place you can find. Perhaps as you said, " between the rear of the 2 sliding shelves."

**BUT**  before you do get yourself some [Fishing sticks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B38KV7BQ).
They are essential for these type of jobs and inexpensive.

If you make your hole in the side of the cabinet with a flat side on the tile, you can fish a stick through the hole in the bottom of the cabinet and get it to be guided by the floor. Sometimes it takes patience, but it can be done.  Then pull your water line and drain through.  You know how to do the rest.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks RMDman.  I did some checking on clearances. Turns out the best spot for the hose to come up from the bottom is the left few inches of the right hand shelf.  This has a 1 3/8 inch clearance to the back wall of the cabinet. For ease of pulling as well as a gentler turn, I think the hole in the bottom needs to be angled. This would allow the hose to pass over the two shelf rail ends on its way up for a loop then into the garbage disposal. The hole position would be 14 inches from the right hand cabinet side.  I do have fish sticks and understand your technique :)

Answer (score 2):

Rethink the slideout.   Get a slightly narrower one or shallower one that leaves some clearance near the cabinet wall on the relevant side.  Or get a two-tier one that fits entirely on the opposite side of the disposal from the dishwasher.  Do you really need a slideout under the disposal?

If the firring is deep enough a passage through the drywall isn't a terrible idea.  Just make the cutout big enough that the space becomes part of the cabinet so you don't appear to be running non-listed cord and plumbing inside a wall